# rxjs call combineLatest in combineLatest

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx

I got a problem with `rxjs` and with `combineLatest` method.
I am trying to call `combineLatest` in `combineLatest` and it doesn't work, although it returns Observable object. Help to resolve the problem, please. `console.log` is never called

Actually, all the observers in the different files, so I can't move `this.search$` to `this.services$`

```
this.search$ = store.select('search');

this.services$ = Observable.combineLatest(
    store.select('currentRegions'),
    store.select('services'),
    (regions, services) => {
        // some filter here
        return services;
    }
);

this.autocomplete$ = Observable.combineLatest(
    this.search$,
    this.services$,
    (search, services) => {
        console.log('show me, please');
        return '';
    }
);
```

Resolved: It doesn't work without any subscriber, so I had to subscribe it

Comment: Most of `observables` are said "cold" which means that when you create them, they won't be run until you subscribe to it.

Answer (score 2):

The `combineLatest()` operator emits a value when all its source Observables emit at least one value.

So if the `console.log(...)` never prints it means that `this.search$` or `this.services$` never emit anything. In other words this means that one of `store.select('currentRegions')`, `store.select('services')` or `store.select('search')` never emit any value.

Note that you can use [`startWith()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-startWith) (even with `startWith(null)`).

This works: https://jsbin.com/gecede/2/edit?js,console

This doesn't work: https://jsbin.com/livafar/2/edit?js,console

Comment: but if I write console.log into `this.services$` callback it will work fine for any editing

Comment: @Hyper See my update with two example that should simulate your situation.

Answer (score 1):

RxJS CombineLatest is kind of AngularJS $q.all

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';


Observable
      .combineLatest(this.store.select('currentRegions'), this.store.select('services')
      .do(console.log)
      .subscribe();
```